# MERGE with Postgresql 11

Tags: postgresql, sql-merge

Wanted to know if PostgreSQL 11 does support MERGE or not.

I read on following articles -

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SQL_MERGE

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SQL_MERGE_Patch_Status

Path overview says that - "Patch for SQL Standard MERGE statement has been submitted to PostgreSQL core"

I also find out other answers here, but all of them for older version only, please help me identify if `MERGE` functionality is implemented with PostgreSQL 11 or not?

Comment: Don't check the Wiki or other sources. The only authoritative source for questions like that is [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html) - and there is no MERGE. Depending on what you want to do, you can most probably use `insert ... on conflict () do update`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for highlighting the `SQL Commands/the manual page`. I wanted to do two table merge base on some keys I have, I am new to this not sure how to do this...

Comment: Maybe with `UNION`?

Comment: thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name, now I could able to achieved my goal using `insert ... on conflict ... do update `